# selenium webdriver, java, Eclipse, Xpath

Tags: internet-explorer, xpath

I was trying to pickup elements on IE 11 using Xpath. I am able to do it in other websites but not for this one. Below is the message i am getting and also tried MRI and i am not able to  locate the elements, it's not picking any element. I ma using Selenium webDriver with java and eclipse. It just the firs page Login.Please help.It lunches the website but not locating any element.

> INFO: Detected dialect: W3C Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element
>   with xpath == //input[@name='EmailAddress' and @id="test;Email
>   Adress;4"] For documentation on this error, please visit:
>   seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: What have you tried? Take a look at [MCVE].

Comment: The code is not more than 10 lines. I was just trying to test the login.It works fine when i just change the url for other website.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest an extension called 'Chropath'. You can install it in your browser and as soon as you enter the website. Go to developer tools and inspect the element in your website. Then click the above place and you can get the chropath from the extension and paste the Xpth (which is the Xpath of the element) and paste it in the IDE and you can assign it to a variable.[image: place you can get the Xpath from Chropath extension]
It would work